# Lost code but I have xcarchive how do I extract my code from it

Tags: xcode, macos

My mac crashed, lost all my code but I have an old xcarchive how do I extract my code from it?

Comment: [You really need to run Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250) (built into MacOS).

Comment: Hard Drive went, I use it once a year to build apps for a customer.

Comment: xcarchive bundles don't contain code, unfortunately. (they contain the compiled app and symbol files and other build product materials)

Comment: Is there anyway to decompile the app?

Comment: Once a week or two someone posts a question like this. How is that so many people don't know to backup important files? Use Time Machine. Use source code control. Archive important files, especially work you are being paid for. More directly, no you can't get your source code back through decompiling or from the archive.

Answer (score 0):

## sorry but you want get back source code that way

the archive only contains compiled code and while you could decompile it in THEORY it won't work in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You all all correct there is no way of doing it, I will have to re-write.

Thank you.